# Unpickling dataframes results in TypeError

Tags: python, dataframe, typeerror, pickle

I'm trying to create a program which creates dataframes from excel files, then puts them together in a dictionary, and finally saves the dictionary as binary file with pickle. Later on I need to access the dictionary with the dataframes.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pickle

path = r'C:/Users/damia/Dropbox/Tesi/WIOD'
dirs = os.listdir(path)

complete_dirs = []
for f in dirs:
    complete_dirs.append(path + r"/" + f)

year = 2000
wiod_dfs = {}
for el in complete_dirs:
    wiod = pd.read_excel(el, engine='pyxlsb')
    wiod_dfs.update({year: wiod})
    year = year + 1

with open('wiods.pkl', 'wb') as wiods:
    pickle.dump(wiod_dfs, wiods)

print('data pickled')

with open('wiods.pkl', 'rb') as wiods:
    wiods_data = pickle.loads(wiods)

print(wiods_data)
```

But the result is:

```
data pickled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\mdthesis\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    wiods_data = pickle.loads(wiods)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, my code looks really similar to the example in the pickle documentation!

Comment: When you write `pickle.loads(wiods)`, what do you think the `s` in `loads` indicates? What does the documentation say about how to call the method? Do you also see a `.load` method?

Comment: Oh, it's a typo, I probably clicked on the wrong suggestion from pyCharm!